# Why is this line rendered without proper antialiasing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to render a line, but if line starts outside the real canvas bounds, I get strange behavior.

For example, I sometimes get this image instead of a proper line:

[image]

Proper line would have looked like this:

[image]

Here's the runnable code to generate this sample:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Render {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(-92, 37, 88, 39));

        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
}
```

I tried using lots of different rendering hints, but no combination gets rid of this problem. What could be the culprit?

*Edit*:

Here's the image with RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE:

[image]

Scaled version of the image (`g.scale(10,10)`):

[image]

Comment: Looks right for a two-pixel line having slope 1/90.

Comment: @trashgod - I attached an image with the right line - it was generated with the same slope and position, but has nice fill for the whole width. Only difference is in shorter off-canvas length - this line was drawn using `g.draw(new Line2D.Double(98,38,188,39))`.

Comment: Maybe the stroke settings, a 2.4. Maybe sub-pixel rendering to be set off (that is _not_ PURE but DEFAULT) - the RGB sub-pixels could have a differing layout than the rendering thinks.

Comment: @JoopEggen Different setting for sub-pixel rendering changes the picture, but the problem still remains (I attached image to the question). I tried using different image types instead of INT_ARGB, but the result is till the same. What can be done about stroke settings?

Comment: For sub-pixel rendering see [createCompatibleBitmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html). For portable non-sub-pixel rendering I merely can advise a 100 times enlargement and checking things out. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried using `createCompatibleBitmap`, nothing changed.

Comment: @JoopEggen I attached scaled version (10x), and it looks very strange - as if my expected line was overlaid with white rectangle for some reason.

Comment: Aha! Try g.fill instead or additional to the line shape. Here g.drawLine would be possible too.

Comment: @JoopEggen - g.fill has absolutely no effect, and g.drawLine does exactly the same thing as g.draw(new Line()).

Comment: Try an other BasicStroke. I leave - out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a *bug* in the algorithm, related to starting off-canvas. (I filed it as such with Oracle (Review ID: JI-9026491, Oracle Bug database: [JDK-8146312](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8146312)))

See this example (Ubuntu 14.04, Java 8u66):

[image]

If I reverse the y-coordinates:

[image]

Final test:

[image]

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        for (int i=0; i<400; i+=5)
        {
            double dy = 8.0*(i-100.0) / 200.0;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.draw(new Line2D.Double(-100, dy+i, 90, i));
            g.draw(new Line2D.Double(200+-100, dy+i, 200+90, i));
        }

        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a link to the page of that bug that you filed? I would be interested in monitoring its progress.

Comment: @Rogach unfortunately not, they don't seem to provide links for bug-submissions while they are not yet approved.

Comment: I just love openness in their development process :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is a bug in the antialiasing algorithm when starting your line outside the canvas.

After playing around a lot with the Renderinghints, moving the line pixel by pixel and analyzing some values like slope, length, portion in- and outside the canvas, I came to the conclusion, that if you don't want to get really deep into the way the antialiasing algorithm at hand works, you will maybe be satisfied with a proper workaround:

1. Start with a huge safezone around the final canvas.
2. Draw the image as usual, just moved by the range of the safezone.
3. Crop away the safezone.

For example:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Render {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // YOUR DESIRED SIZE OF CANVAS
        int size = 100;
        // THE SAFEZONE AROUND THE CANVAS
        int safezone = 1000;

        // THE IMAGE GETS INITIALIZED WITH SAFEZONE APPLIED
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size+safezone, size+safezone, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        // THE IMAGE GETS FILLED, DON'T FORGET THE SAFEZONE
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size+safezone, size+safezone);

        // THE ORIGINAL VALUES WITH THE SAFEZONE APPLIED
        int x1 = -92 + safezone/2;
        int x2 = 88 + safezone/2;
        int y1 = 37 + safezone/2;
        int y2 = 39 + safezone/2;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));

        g.dispose();

        // CROP THE IMAGE
        image = image.getSubimage(safezone/2, safezone/2, size, size);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
}
```

This will give you:

[image: cropped]

While using your exact values. The code must of course be fitted to your needs, but for the sake of the example, it works.

While this is not a beautiful solution, the results are and I hope it helps! :)

Comment: If you still like to anaylize, you can paste this code below the point, where the image gets written:  `x1 -= safezone/2;
  x2 -= safezone/2;
  y1 -= safezone/2;
  y2 -= safezone/2;
  
  double length = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  double slope = (((double)x2-x1))/(y2-y1);
  
  System.out.println("Slope: " + slope);
  System.out.println("Length: " + length);
  System.out.println("Point 1: " + x1 + " | " + y1);
  System.out.println("Point 2: " + x2 + " | " + y2);
  System.out.println("Part Inside: " + x2/length);
  System.out.println("Part Outside: " + Math.abs(x1/length));`

Comment: Yes, this solution is working. Unfortunately, I need to create lots of such images per second, and safezone will have to be huge - I will quickly run out of available memory if I will add it to every tile.

Comment: Instead of rendering lines that you cannot see anyway, you could just calculate the point where the line meets the edge of the canvas, and start your line there. That's very cheap (one method, and some basic mathematics). Especially when compared to rendering.

Comment: Good idea @RobAu ! Some other quick ideas, not knowing what exactly your code should do in the end: **1.** If you can get that information beforehand, you can limit the safezone to the value and sides of the farthest points outside the canvas. **2.** If this results in a video, you could just crop the video in post. **3.** If cropping is the part that makes your calculations slow, maybe your can just cover the part to crop with something else or limit the viewport to the important section of your image?

Comment: **4.** As it seems this bug only appears when the lines **starts** outside the canvas, you could add a small line of code that reverses start and end of the lines starting outside, so they always start inside the canvas. @RobAu

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observe is not related to the fact that the line start outside the canvas. If you use a line completely inside the canvas you will observe the same behavior.

The problem is coming from the combination of a small slope `dy/dx=1/90`, a small width (`2`) and the antialiasing algorithm.

### Without antialiasing

[image]

```
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
```

### With antialiasing

[image]

```
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

The behavior you observe is completly normal and is due to the antialiasing algorithm.

Comment: Please look at the my first example picture - it was drawn with antialiasing ON, but it doesn't look anything like your second picture.

Comment: And if I start the line inside the canvas (or even outside, but not very far away), I will observe very different behavior, as can be seen in my second example picture.

Comment: I've modified the images using the exact same settings as you. The only change is on the KEY_ANTIALIASING.

Comment: If you start the line outside the canvas, you will change the slope and that's probably the reason of the differences you see.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that (8,37)->(188,39) has the same slope as (98,38)->(188,39) - 1/90?

Comment: And these two lines even end at exactly the same point - so they should look exactly the same.

Comment: I've drawn the two lines you cited in your example:  (8,37)->(188,39) and (98,38)->(188,39). If I translate by dx=-90 the second line (`g.translate(-90, 0);`), I obtain two identical images.

Comment: In fact, almost identical there is one pixel difference at the border probably due to border conditions and clipping in the antialiasing algorithm.

Comment: Strange - so you don't see this problem at all? Maybe there are problems with my concrete environment - what OS do you use?

Comment: I tried this both on XUbuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 (both have jdk 8u66 installed) and the result is pixel-for-pixel same as in my first image.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example with a Path2D instead of a Line2D improves the output.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
    path.moveTo(-92, 37);
    path.lineTo(88, 39);
    g.draw(path);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with the rendering in your specific case which your sample line started in `x = -92` (location of the starting point of your line and the slope is an exception in this scale). But as you may noticed there is no problem with the values outside of the canvas like `x = -12` or `x = -22` or `x = -82` or even `x = -102`. The only hint you need to advice is:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

and I think if `g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));` is not really matters, you can change it to `g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));` or even omit it completely. This will make you line smoother.